# printing 2D array list with a line break between each list

Tags: python, python-3.x

while practicing python3 I have found some difficulties while I was doing some challenges. I am trying to print the list with a line break between movies_1 and movies_2, which i made it as 2D array. I have used "\n" for a line break. However it doesnt seems to work. What other way is there I could do to fix this ?

```
movies_1 = [
["a", "b", "c"]
["d", "e", "f"]
]

movies_2 =[
["g", "h", "i"]
["j", "k", "l"]
]
```

While initially printed the following.

```
print(movies_1, movies_2)
```

Which gave me this

```
[['a', 'b', 'c']['d', 'e', 'f']['g', 'h', 'i']['j', 'k', 'l']]
```

But it was so messy messy so i wanted to organise it giving line breaks.

I wish the following list to print as following

```
[['a', 'b', 'c']['d', 'e', 'f']

['g', 'h', 'i']['j', 'k', 'l']]
```

So I have tried this so far

```
print(movies_1, + "\n" + movies_2)
```

However, what I get when I use the above print is
bad operand type for unary +: str

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### List Definitions:

```py
movies_1 = [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["d", "e", "f"]
]

movies_2 = [
    ["g", "h", "i"],
    ["j", "k", "l"]
]
```

### Lots of Print Options:

#### [Format Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```py
print(f'{movies_1}\n{movies_2}')
```

```py
print("{}\n{}".format(movies_1, movies_2))
```

```py
print("{0}\n{1}".format(movies_1, movies_2))
```

---

#### Commas with [Print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```py
print(movies_1, '\n', movies_2)
```

---

#### String Concatenation:

```py
print(str(movies_1) + '\n' + str(movies_2))
```

---

#### [Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) With [Join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```py
print('\n'.join([str(m) for m in [movies_1, movies_2]]))
```

---

#### Series of [Prints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```py
print(movies_1)
print(movies_2)
```

Comment: Right ! I see what mistakes I have made so far. If you dont mind, may I ask why I need to do str(movies_1) ? Believed list would've been a string ?

Comment: No `list` and `str` are different data types. `print` automatically attempts to make any object a printable type via [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr), however, when you try to add a `str` to a `list` (`movies_1 + '\n'` for example) that is where you have type issues.

Answer (score 0):

`format` in print statements is very handy in python

Try this:

```
print("{}\n{}".format(movies_1,movies_2))
```

Comment: Cheers, that definitely workd and was one way I definitely didn't think about.